# Change text on hover using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this markup and CSS

```
<div class="share-btn">
  20 Shares
  <span>Share Now</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.share-btn span{
  display: none;
}
.share-btn:hover {
  display: none;
}

.share-btn:hover span {
  display: block;
}
```

I'm trying to change the text on mouse hover. Hovering `20 Shares` should change to `Share Now`. I tried with CSS but not working as I expected.

How can I do this using CSS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="share-btn">
  <span id="one">20 Shares</span>
  <span id="two">Share Now</span>
</div>
```

css

```
 .share-btn #two{
      display: none;
    }

    .share-btn:hover #one {
      display: none;
    }

    .share-btn:hover #two {
      display: block
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can't use id because I have multiple share buttons.